# $ \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} 1 + e^{1/x}$ (Definition)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Using the definition of limit, I need to show that $\lim_{x \to 0^-} 1 + e^{1/x} =1$.

Using the definition, I have that $x > \frac{1}{\ln \epsilon}(|e^{1/x}|=e^{1/x} < \epsilon)$, but this is not helping since I need a positive delta. Also, I coudn't deal with the case $\epsilon = 1$

Can you help me with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $e^{1/x} < \varepsilon \iff \dfrac1x < \ln \varepsilon \iff \dfrac1{\ln\varepsilon} < x < 0$.

Comment: Oh, I think I did something wrong with the signs, then. How about the case $\epsilon = 1$? Should we be worried with it?

Comment: No, you need to worry about sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$ only.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure about it :) Thanks

Comment: I was thinking about this exercise again and how you conclude that $ -\frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon} < x < 0$. It is true, for $ 0<\varepsilon<1$ that $ \frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon} < x < 0$. But, $ -\frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon} < \frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon} $ if $ \varepsilon > 1 $, right? In this case, what should be my delta? $ \delta = \min${$\frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon}, - \frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon}$} ? Thanks

Comment: We only need sufficiently small values of $\varepsilon$, i.e. we can assume that $\varepsilon < 1$. But I am sorry, there is no need for "minus", corrected now.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear :) thank you very much!